# javascript error in jquery: string.replace( rmsPrefix, "ms-" ) javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, runtime-error

I am seeing this error locally. it happens when i append some certain DOM:

```
TypeError: string is undefined  

return string.replace( rmsPrefix, "ms-" ).replace( rdashAlpha, fcamelCase );

jquery.js (line 622)
```

It doesnt appear on production, but it happens to me locally from time to time. Ive debugged it but couldnt find anything. Im using jquery 1.8.2.

Posting about it here in hopes some one else has come across this. (i dont expect a solution)

here is the code that causes it:

```
flash = function(type, message, secondaryMessage) {
    var flash_location = $('.flash-location');
    var secondary = '';
    type = type || 'error';
    message = message || (type == 'success' ? 'Success' : 'Error');
    if(secondaryMessage){
        secondary = '<p class="secondary">'+secondaryMessage+'</p>';
    }
    var top = 5;
    flash_location.append($('<div class="flash"><div class="flash-content ' + type + '" style="top:'+top+'px;"><table><tr><td class="flash-icon"></td><td><p class="primary">' + message + '</p>'+secondary+'</td></tr></table></div></div>').fadeIn('normal'));
};
```

Comment: How can we tell? (assuming we are not mind readers) Maybe a larger scope could help...

Comment: I think string is reserved word or variable string is undefined.

Comment: show your code where you using this `replace()`

Comment: Try to past console.log(string) before returning your string. Is it not undefined as well?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only place where this function (`$.camelCase`) is called and passes `undefined` through is `.css`. Are you calling `$("...").css(undefined, "...")` somehow?

Comment: this may be frowned upon by the stackoverflow overlords but i created this question so that searching for the said error yields results. As i said, ive debugged this. yes the string is undefined, and the stacktrace is very deep and leads into event code. I am **not** calling css with undefined.

Comment: camelCase is used throughout jQuery. If we can't see any of your code we can't tell what call is passing undefined as an argument to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem still occur if you build your `append` elements using the DOM?

```
flash = function(type, message, secondaryMessage) {
    var flash_location = $('.flash-location'),
        top = 5,
        table = $('<table />'),
        tr = $('<tr />'),
        td = $('<td />'),
        p = $('<p />'),
        div = $('<div />'),
        td1 = td.clone().addClass('flash-icon'),
        td2 = td.clone().append(p.clone().addClass('primary')),
        flashContent = div.clone().addClass('flash-content').addClass(type).css('top', top + 'px'),
        flash = div.clone().addClass('flash');
    type = type || 'error';
    message = message || (type == 'success' ? 'Success' : 'Error');
    if(secondaryMessage){
        td2.append(p.clone().addClass('secondary').text(secondaryMessage));
    }
    tr.append(td1).append(td2);
    table.append(tr);
    flashContent.append(table);
    flash.append(flashContent);
    flash_location.append(flash).fadeIn('normal'));
};
```